# Convert List<IInfrastructureEntity> to List<TEntity> where generic type TEntity necessarily implements that interface

Tags: c#, asp.net, generics, interface

I have a static class `DataSource` that pulls requested data from a file and returns it as a `List<IInfrastructureEntity>.` In `TestRepository` (below), I am taking the generic `TEntity`, determining its class type and pulling the corresponding data from `DataSource`  Or, trying to, at least. Instead, I get the following compile-time error on each return statement.  Even though any`TEntity` necessarily implements `IInfrastructureEntity`.

Cannot implicitly convert type '`System.Collections.Generic.List<IInfrastructureEntity>`' to '`System.Collections.Generic.List<TEntity>`'

How do I explicitly make that conversion?

```
public class TestRepository<TEntity> : IRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : IInfrastructureEntity
{
    public List<TEntity> GetData()
    {
        TEntity checkType = default(TEntity);
        if (checkType is Member) return DataSource.Members;
        if (checkType is MenuItem) return DataSource.MenuItems;
        if (checkType is CRAWApplication) return DataSource.CRAWApplications;
        if (checkType is CRAWEntitlement) return DataSource.CRAWEntitlements;
        if (checkType is FOXGroup) return DataSource.FOXGroups;

        throw new NotSupportedException( checkType.ToString() + " is not yet supported");
    }

    public List<TEntity> FindBy(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate)
    {
        return GetData().AsQueryable().Where(predicate);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could fix this by imposing an explicit cast in each list your return:

```
if (checkType is Member) return DataSource.Members.Cast<TEntity>().ToList();
```

The problem is that the type of `DataSource.Members` is `List<IInfrastructureEntity>`, whereas the type that is expected to be returned is a `List<TEntity>`. Indeed each `Entity` should implement `IInfrastructureEntity` as you have stated this as `where TEntity : IInfrastructureEntity`. However even if a type implements this interface it doesn't mean that this type can be converted implicitly to `TEntity` object. This is why you need the explicit cast.

Comment: Oy! Is that what it was? Thank you.